# Intuition on YOLO bounding box width & height normalization formula

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, yolo

I found an article on how to compute yolo bounding box coordinates: x, y, width, height

[image]

[image]

http://christopher5106.github.io/object/detectors/2017/08/10/bounding-box-object-detectors-understanding-yolo.html

I dont understand what is the idea and intuition behind this computation? How does this lead to width and height be normalized to (0,1) relative to the original image?